# ¿Cómo recorro una lista para obtener un index específico y sumar el valor de estos, usando Java streams?

Tags: java, bucles, arraylist, sum, java-stream

//tengo una lista

List<Object[]> data = Arrays.asList(

new Object[]{"aaa", 2816},

new Object[]{"bbb", 2322},

new Object[]{"ccc", 4187});

//Necesito obtener el index 1 para luego sumar los valores
//Hice este método Imperativo //(no la he probado aún).

long totalAmount = 0;

for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++) {

```
totalAmount=+(long) data.get(i)[1];
```

}

//Pero Declarativa???

Desde ya gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: This question is suitable for the English site, you can use `collect (Collectors.summarizingLong()` ;)

Comment: Mejor la traduzco y la publicaré en el otro sitio también

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizar streams en este caso es muy sencillo. Solo necesitas mapear el arreglo de objetos a un `IntStream` usando `mapToInt` y luego llamar a la función `sum()`. Quedaría en una línea:

```
long sum = data.stream().mapToInt(array -> (Integer) array[1]).sum();
```

Te adjunto un ejemplo completo que puedes ejecutar online en [este enlace](https://onlinegdb.com/xUZur6jtR):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object[]> data = Arrays.asList(
                new Object[]{"aaa", 2816},
                new Object[]{"bbb", 2322},
                new Object[]{"ccc", 4187});

        long sum = data.stream().mapToInt(array -> (Integer) array[1]).sum();
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, veré si me funciona. Había estado probando con mapToInt y sum pero no me ha funcionado aún.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, gracias!